# Push Split View iPad

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

Is there any way that i can Push a SplitViewController in my app?
I have a regular view and when the user clicks a button, i would like to push a SplitViewController.
Simple as that, I can find anything to help on Google.

Comment: Adding to what has been answered below, you can find the information in Apple documentation at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html    "A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no way to push SplitViewController.** If you want to use it according to apple it needs to be the root view of your application.

There is a workaround for that though (not %100 gauranteed to be accepted by apple). You need to change the Root of your main Window in **AppDelegate** manually and animate it yourself.

**Edit:**

I found some code for changing the `rootViewController` of the window:

```
AppDelegate delegate = [[UIApllication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[delegate window] rootViewController] = yourSplitViewController;
```

Comment: @DiegoRodrigues have a look at the edit I posted. There's a small code snippet that might interest you!

Comment: Where i put this code? Sorry i'm very new.
And how I define my other ViewController to be the root and open when the app starts?

Comment: Wherever you want to push. Keep in mind that this is not necessarily a push and if you want to keep the state of your last view (the one that you want to push from), you need to keep a reference to it and change the view manually when you want to close down the split view.